# regex validation for only specific characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create regular expression for specific code, here are the requirements

1. Length should be 13
2. First letter starts with X
3. Next letters A-Z and 0-9 should accept
4. Only capital letters

Ex : XAABBCC88EE00

I created this expression `^[X]{1}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$`, But it's not working. How Can I create one for this

Comment: use this `^X[A-Z0-9]{12}$`

Comment: 1) `[X]{1}` = `X`. 2) Why did you use `-` in the regex if there is no `-` in your input string?

Comment: Also exclude `a-z`, as you specified you don't want lowercase. Look up the different "opreators" you're using here, rather than predefined regexes you piece together.

Answer (score 2):

```
^X[A-Z0-9]{12}$
```

Here is what it does:

- ^ asserts start of a line.
- X the code should start with the letter "X".
- [A-Z0-9]{12} ensures that the next 12 characters can be any
  uppercase letter (A-Z) or digit (0-9).
- $ asserts end of a line.

This regular expression ensures that the code is exactly 13 characters long, starts with "X", and the remaining 12 characters are either uppercase letters or digits.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake in your pattern `^[X]{1}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$`

*The mistake*:- you wrote `[a-zA-Z0-9]` this will accept small and capital alphabets plus the numbers.

**The Solution**:-
The required pattern should be `/^[X]{1}[A-Z0-9]{12}$/`, this will accept the input as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your thought process for your regex is to define first character length and then other characters length which is not required

If you use `^X[A-Z0-9]{12}$` it will work, below is the explanation

`^` Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled. This matches a position, not a character

`X` Character matches "X" character (Case sensitive)

`A-Z` and `0-9` Matches the exact character A-Z and 0-9 (Case sensitive)

`{12}` Quantifier matches 12 digits allowed after X